# How to run ADF test on a time series. Need to divide the series by two criteria first and get results for each separately in a neat table

Tags: r

Need to run the Augmented Dickey–Fuller test on a time series. There are 3 groups of people and 4 categories of products. I'd need to run the ADF test so that I get results for each group and each product category separately, organised in a table.

Supose a df containing spendings of 3 groups of people on 4 categories of products:

```r
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(aTSA)

data_df <- data.frame(Group = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 12)),
                      Category = rep(c(rep(111, 3), rep(112, 2), 
                                  rep(121, 5), rep(122, 2)), 3),
                      Spending = rnorm(36, 10, 3))
```

The spendings were done in certain years (assuming it was halfyear). For the purpose of ADF test we need a ts:

```r
data_xts <- as.xts(data_df, order.by = ymd(rep(paste0(2005:2016, "07-01"), 3)))
```

First thing is:

1. **how do I access certain results of the test, say: p-value of Type 1, with 0 lag.**
2. **The other (more important thing) is: how to divide the table by the two criteria ("Group" and "Category")**  to get the results of the test in a neat way like such:

```
Group  Category p-value
1      111        0.123
1      112        0.456
...
```

If didn't need to split I'd just use `adf.test(data_xts$Spending)`

I tried to use `split()` but this way I could only divide the table by one criterion and also this got me a list of dataframes that I didn't know what to do with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `split` the original dataframe, not the `xts` series, by a *list* with members `Group` and `Category`. Then run the tests on each resulting list members.

```
sp <- split(data_df, list(data_df$Group, data_df$Category))

res <- lapply(sp, function(DF) {
  err <- tryCatch(
    adf.test(DF[['Spending']], nlag = 1),
    error = function(e) e)
})
```

Now see which had errors and keep the others.

```
keep <- !sapply(res, inherits, "error")

OK <- res[keep]
ERR <- res[!keep]
```

Finally, extract the `type?` results into a matrix.

```
Type1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK, '[[', 'type1'))
Type2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK, '[[', 'type2'))
Type3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK, '[[', 'type3'))
rownames(Type1) <- names(OK)
rownames(Type2) <- names(OK)
rownames(Type3) <- names(OK)

Type1
#      lag         ADF    p.value
#1.111   0 -0.71919548 0.41178921
#2.111   0 -2.03281443 0.04332142
#3.111   0  0.14723783 0.67762240
#1.121   0 -0.04341668 0.62275779
#2.121   0 -1.78744138 0.07322266
#3.121   0 -0.45198372 0.50518454
```

**Default `nlag` value.**

In the code above I have used `nlag = 1`.
The `aTSA::adf.test` documentation says (note the typo) that the default lag is used to compute the test statistic.

> We use the default nlag = floor(4*(length(x)/100)^(2/9)) to calcuate
>   the test statistic.

To do this the code would become as follows.

```
res_b <- lapply(sp, function(DF) {
  err <- tryCatch(
    adf.test(DF[['Spending']]),
    error = function(e) e)
})

keep <- !sapply(res, inherits, "error")

OK_b <- res_b[keep]
ERR_b <- res_b[!keep]

Type1_b <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK_b, '[[', 'type1'))
Type2_b <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK_b, '[[', 'type2'))
Type3_b <- do.call(rbind, lapply(OK_b, '[[', 'type3'))
rownames(Type1_b) <- sapply(names(OK), paste, unique(Type1_b[, 'lag']), sep = '.')
rownames(Type2_b) <- sapply(names(OK), paste, unique(Type2_b[, 'lag']), sep = '.')
rownames(Type3_b) <- sapply(names(OK), paste, unique(Type3_b[, 'lag']), sep = '.')

Type1_b
#        lag         ADF    p.value
#1.121.0   0 -0.04341668 0.62275779
#1.121.1   1  0.37003728 0.74173735
#1.121.2   2         NaN        NaN
#2.121.0   0 -1.78744138 0.07322266
#2.121.1   1 -1.16668314 0.25338650
#2.121.2   2         NaN        NaN
#3.121.0   0 -0.45198372 0.50518454
#3.121.1   1  0.03268111 0.64465644
#3.121.2   2         NaN        NaN
```